# Besides oil and the oil wealth stash, Russia has precious little - what does precious little mean?

Tags: meaning

> If oil hits $75-80, Aslund said "Russia would have to cut its imports, which would hit the standard of living, investment and economic growth. A decline in GDP and standard of living would be inevitable."
>   Besides oil and the oil wealth stash, Russia has **precious little**.

What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase ["precious little"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/precious-little-or-few) means to have very little/very few left.

> **precious little (or few)**
>
> extremely little or few (used for emphasis):
>   "police still know precious little about the dead man"

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-cobuild-learners/precious) describes "precious little" this way:

> If you say that there is **precious little** of something, you are emphasizing that there is very little of it, and that it would be better if there were more.

An example from the same source:

> The banks have had precious little to celebrate recently.

Answer (score 1):

Precious little means *very little*. Russia will have very little left to live on if its oil revenues slump and its oil-based capital wears out.

See the adverbial sense of *[precious](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/precious)* at Wiktionary:

> **precious** (not comparable)
>   Used as an intensifier.
>   *There is precious little we can do.*

In other words, "[All we've got is cotton, slaves and arrogance](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S72nI4Ex_E0#t=59)."

Comment: +1 this is new to me . I always used *pretty* in such case. Thanks :)